# Create Azure Service Principal for Service App using the CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps service endpoint to connect to Azure Resource Manager and to deploy my app into a App Service.

When I go to Azure DevOps > Project Properties and create a Service Endpoint  using the UI (Automated dialog) it works fine and my app can be deployed to App Service from a yaml pipeline, BUT, when I try to replicate it thru the Azure CLI it doesn't work (the build fails to deploy complaining about the Service Principal).

This is my code:

```
az_account=$(az account show)
az_subscription_id=$(echo $az_account |jq -r '.id')
az_subscription_name=$(echo $az_account |jq -r '.name')
az_tenant_id=$(echo $az_account |jq -r '.tenantId')
az_service_principal=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "my-app-service-principal")
az_service_principal_password=$(echo $az_service_principal|jq -r '.password')
az_service_principal_id=$(az ad sp list --all | jq -c '.[] | select( .appDisplayName | contains("my-app-service-principal"))'| jq -r '.objectId')
export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_AZURE_RM_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_KEY=$az_service_principal_password
az devops service-endpoint azurerm create --azure-rm-service-principal-id $az_service_principal_id --azure-rm-subscription-id $az_subscription_id --azure-rm-subscription-name $az_subscription_name --azure-rm-tenant-id $az_tenant_id --name my-app-service-endpoint
```

How should I create this Service Enpoint programatically with the Azure CLI?

Updated with the Azure DevOps error:
[image: error]

Comment: whats the error you are getting when running the builds?

Comment: added to the op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script simply creates the Service Principal but it is not giving any permission to the SP.
I would add some lines like these to create a Resource Group and scope permission to it

```
az_service_principal_appid = $(echo $az_service_principal|jq -r '.appId')
az group create --name myrg --location westeurope
az role assignment create --role Contributor --assignee $az_service_principal_appid --resource-group myrg
```

Clearly you need to think how to arrange your resources and SPs: you may need many of both depending on your architecture.

Comment: It didn't work. If I go to the service endpoint and azure devops and press "Verify connection" it says:

Comment: Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) using service principal client ID. Exception Message: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'a9fd87a4-c0b5-46f6-b4a1-XXXXXXXXX' was not found in the directory '0cf92556-5b1c-405b-99cf-XXXXXXXXX'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: 0abb8f63-8e9c-416c-b084-XXXXXXXXX Correlation ID: b6f0445e-5718-40cb-8594-XXXXXXXXX Timestamp: 2019-10-03 08:21:51Z

Comment: just to let you know resource group service app  service plan etc is deployed with terraform. the only problem is with automating the azure devops service endpoint creation and or service principal. all the rest works fine if i deploy these two things from the azure devops service endpoint page using the ui and the automated dialog

Comment: the error `Application with identifier '' was not found in the directory` seems to me that you are passing the wrong id (they are all similar, what a shame)
I updated my answer in case it helps
BTW I often use Terraform in conjunction with Pipelines, I suggest to use Azure Portal as a debugging tool to check IDs and permissions